# Why are "get-hotfix" and "wmic qfe list" in Powershell missing installed updates?

Tags: windows, powershell, hotfix

I'm trying to write a script to make sure a certain hotfix is installed. On one of our test computers running Windows 8.1, `get-hotfix` returns an incomplete list of hotfixes:

[image]

Yet there are tons of patches showing in the Programs and Features control panel:

[image]

All of our other test machines, including others installed with Windows 8.0 and 8.1, work fine. Any idea why this is? How can I get a complete list of hotfixes from Powershell?

**Edit:** `wmic qfe list` only shows the same four hotfixes as `get-hotfix` as well.

Comment: Thanks @PJMahoney -- I tried those suggestions without luck. `get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering` shows the same results as `get-hotfix`.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the `Get-Hotfix` commandlet leverages the [`Win32_QuickFixEngineering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394391(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class to list Windows Updates, but only returns updates supplied by [Component Based Servicing (CBS)](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx).  Updates supplied by the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) or the Windows update site are not returned by `Get-Hotfix`/`Win32_QuickFixEngineering`.

You can try using the Windows Update API through PowerShell like in the below example.  Give this a shot and let us know if it shows the missing updates.

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | ft -a Date,Title
```

**EDIT:** To search through the results, you can use the `Where-Object`  commandlet (or alias `Where`) and filter for a specific hotfix:

```
$Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | Where {$_.Title -like "*KB2760587*"} | ft date,title
```

Comment: Thanks @bentek! That does it. Since I'm pretty new to Powershell, would you mind also showing me a good way to query those results to find if a specific hotfix is included?

Comment: Also, is this less compatible with older Windows versions than `get-hotfix`?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a simple query for a specific hotfix.

Comment: Actually, this is reporting updates as being installed that aren't listed under Programs and Features --> Installed Updates.

Comment: It looks like I want to use `$Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | ft -a Date,Title` instead.

Comment: Nice catch.  I've updated the example code accordingly.

Comment: FYI: See also: `Microsoft Update Client Install History` under https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx for a different version of this solution (for me the above failed, but it led me to this Technet link which worked).

Comment: @bentek I have some understanding issues. The pages mentions Clients like msi or Windows Update pass their packages to CBS, which then further handles the installation. What does "supplied by CBS" mean in that context? It rather reads as the two are working together 24/7.

Also thanks for the script, it seems to return at least the update I was looking for, but it literally takes hours to finish...why is that?

Comment: Win10 KB4561616 not showing up with this or wmic qfe :( tweaking the last line of powershell per guidance linked on https://superuser.com/a/1241220/160219 solved

Comment: `$Searcher.Search(...)` did not work for me. I had to use `$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount())` to get a list of installed updates. Nearly all the differences between this component and `Get-Hotfix` were updates to the antivirus/antimalware application (under the dozen or so names MS has used for it in the past decade). I also came across a known bug on one server from KB4034658 where this update history simply doesn't work, so that one had to rely on `Get-Hotfix`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use different ways to  list the updates installed by different methods. like installed by wsus or configmgr

Take a look here

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If someday someone needs to get the full update list using Python, I've written in implementation that checks for windows updates via COM, WMI and registry so we don't miss an update based on it's install method.

Install with:

```
pip install windows_tools.updates
```

Usage

```
from windows_tools.updates import get_windows_updates

for update in get_windows_updates(filter_duplicates=True):
    print(update)
```

You can also remove the duplicate filter (AV engine updates etc) with `get_windows_updates(filter_multiple=False)`