# Why is Microsoft.Update.Session so slow? Can I make it faster?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm running this script script (as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1002015)):

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | ft -a Date,Title
```

However, the `Search()` method takes **up to 10 minutes** on some of the machines I'm testing on!

- Why is this so slow? The list in Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Installed Updates only takes a few seconds.
- Can I make this faster? I'm only looking to see if one particular update is in the list.
- What format is the `"IsInstalled=1"` query in? If I make a mistake, `Search()` returns *all* updates, which isn't very helpful. **Edit:** Documentation is here - [IUpdateSearcher::Search method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386526(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It's probably (also) searching remotely. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DanielB I'm trying to see if a particular update is installed -- that's all I need. I can't use `Get-Hotfix` because [sometimes it's incorrect](http://superuser.com/questions/1002015).

Comment: For now, check if the `systeminfo` command is right enough.

Comment: @DanielB I was excited to try this, but `systeminfo` appears to miss hotfixes just like `Get-Hotfixes` does. (I have a Win8.1 host here that shows four hotfixes with `systeminfo` and `Get-Hotfixes`, but I get the full list in Programs and Features and by using `CreateUpdateSearcher()`.

Comment: @PJMahoney Thanks! Looks like others have found similar problems.

Comment: found any better working solution? For me it takes hours..

Comment: @taclight No, I never found a solution to this. :(

Comment: @apaidnerd oh well then I'll just continue trying to apply any given update and see if it works or doesn't :D

Comment: I've found "<ISearcher.>QueryHistory()" to be much faster.  Check here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.windows-how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx