# PowerShell's 'Get-Hotfix' and 'Win32_QuickFixEngineering' WMI class doesn't return any results

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-update, wmi

`Get-Hotfix` doesn't appear to be working on one of our Windows 10 1803 machines - it doesn't return any results, no errors either. It's the same with `Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Select HotfixID` and `wmic qfe list`. However, all updates - including the recent 2020-01 updates - are installed and appearing in Add/Remove Programs (our updates are pushed out via SCCM). So it's curious why Get-Hotfix isn't working on this system.

I suspected system component corruption, so I ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:X:\Windows /LimitAccess` using a good source and that worked without any errors, rebooted, followed it up with an `SFC /SCANNOW` that found and fixed all detected corruptions and rebooted. Still broken. As a last resort, I rebuilt the WMI repository using the instructions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fieldcoding/resetting-wmi-repository-dos-and-donts

Unfortunately that didn't work either. Finally I decided to reset/re-register all the Windows Update components following this article: https://pureinfotech.com/reset-windows-update-windows-10-fix-downloads-installs/ but that didn't do anything either.

I'm at a total loss now. Is there anything else I can try besides rebuilding the machine (which seems to be a bit overkill as everything else appears to be working normally). The system is at a remote location and on a low bandwidth link, so it isn't really a feasible to do a reinstall/swap.

---

**FYI** @**harrymc** and others: [Why are "get-hotfix" and "wmic qfe list" in Powershell missing installed updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002015/why-are-get-hotfix-and-wmic-qfe-list-in-powershell-missing-installed-updates) does **NOT** answer my question. First of all, the problems are different - in OP's case the command at least lists *some* updates, but not in my case. Second, none of the "solutions" posted there are actual solutions, what I need to know is how do I fix the broken Windows Update / WMI component that's resulting in zero output by all the usual commands.

Comment: In a PS command window (doesn't need to be admin), what happens if you run: `((New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher()).Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | ft -a title`

Comment: @HelpingHand: That only returns three Visual C++ runtimes, doesn't return any actual OS patches.