# Get-HotFix shows no results

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

This is similar to the question asked here but is over 3 years old, so I will ask again: [PowerShell's 'Get-Hotfix' and 'Win32_QuickFixEngineering' WMI class doesn't return any results](https://superuser.com/questions/1518350/powershells-get-hotfix-and-win32-quickfixengineering-wmi-class-doesnt-retu)

Get-HotFix from PS is installed, however not showing anything. Same with the commands from the link.

Attempted same steps described. Is there any insight to what would be causing this?

Comment: Can you clarify if you have the exact same behavior, like do `wmic qfe list` or `(New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates` show any updates? If you're installing updates using an automated tool like SCCM, then you may need to use one of those instead